# what's the color of interior of ellipse?

Tags: c++, mfc, cdc

In MFC:
If I use CBrush like `"CBrush brush; CDC* pDC = GetDC();pDC->Ellipse(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);",`
what color of the ellipse's interior will be?

Comment: You realize you don't even use `brush`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the brush or assigning it anything; it's simply a variable declaration. It serves absolutely no purpose, so you'd see whatever color was set for the brush in `pDC`.

If you've done nothing to change it, the interior of the ellipsis will be whatever the default background color is for the device context in `pDC`.

Comment: Then what color of the ellipse's interior will be? pDC is "CDC* pDC = GetDC();" no more codes about brush.

Comment: I answered that - whatever color the brush in `pDC` is set to be. What part of that isn't clear? You've done nothing to change what the device context (contained in `pDC`) already has. My question to you is "What happens when you try it?".

Comment: Thank you after all, maybe my question is not so clear, so I changed it.

Comment: The answer is still the same: It's whatever color the brush in `pDC` is, no matter how many times you ask it. :-)

Comment: I think you can help me solve the headache in  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532470/why-function-ellipse-are-needed-twice-here-to-draw-an-ellipse", thanks.